# Stop Android WebView automatically creating (focusable) links

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

I'm using a WebView to display some (locally stored) HTML. The WebView automatically converts various parts of the text to clickable links; this is somewhat useful for web addresses, etc. but it often unfortunately mistakes numbers (especially years) in the page as phone numbers and turns them into links also.

Assume I am happy to disable all links in the page. Visually, I can get part-way there by applying various [CSS styles](http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit.php), in particular, setting appropriate values for `-webkit-touch-callout` and `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` will make the links appear as normal text. I can then set a custom `WebViewClient` which overrides `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` (returning true) to prevent the WebView loading the URL.

For touch access, this works fine and certainly gives the impression that there are no links in the page. However, if used on a device with a trackball/directional pad we can still focus on each of the links, and an orange border appears around them.

Is there any way to (ideally) have more control over the auto-linking 'feature' of a WebView, or otherwise stop links from being visually focused when using a directional pad?

Comment: Did you try `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />`. Also try `outline:0` to remove the orange border.